# File backup, free for commercial use

Tags: windows, gratis, backup, portable

I just want to backup a single directory. I need a gratis Windows app, with its own scheduler (I don't want to use the Windows scheduler).

The app ***must ***:

- either all allow me to schedule the backup at regular intervals, or support mirroring in real-time; I don't really care which.
- be portable and not wrtite to the Windows registry
- have a ***very clear*** statement that it is free for commercial use, which I can show to my non-technical manager.

Th... th... th...that's all, folks :-)

Comment: Since you are requiring Windows, why not just use the built in robocopy utility?   The only one of your requirements it doesn't have is its own scheduler...

Comment: Because, as the question states, "I don't want to use the Windows scheduler"

Comment: What's wrong with the Windows scheduler?

Comment: Long story, doesn't matter. It's a  requirement not to use it.